# Visually formatting chart issue

Tags: c#, charts

This is an incredibly localized problem but I've spent a while on it now and just can't get the formatting to work. Basically what I want to do is show a column chart for a value but no bells and whistles (i.e. no labeling, no title, no legend, nothing!) And I want it to look like this:
[image: Desired image]

But instead it looks like this:

[image: Actual image]

The axis extends out and to the right and I can't figure out how to make it go away. Here is my code:

```
charts[i].Series.Clear();
charts[i].Series.Add("Block " + i + 1);
charts[i].Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
charts[i].Series[0].Points.Add(liveData[i]);
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 4;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LineWidth = 0;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
charts[i].Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;
```

Now I am guessing this is a `min`/`max` thing but for the life of me I just can't get it to work. Can someone see my mistake? Or suggest another method besides charts?

Also note the 'Block 1 (V)' label you see underneath is not generated by the chart, it is a `textbox` label that just happened to get cut into the screenshot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has the x-value of 1. By default the bar is centered on the 1 mark. by shifting the limits you are actually only seeing half of it. Two things to do: Tell the bar exactly how wide it shall be and limit the x-axes accordingly.

```
charts[i].Series[0].CustomProperties = "PointWidth = 1"; // One bar takes a width of 1 unit on the x-axis
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0.5; // change!
charts[i].ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1.5; // change!
```